# How to fix Error: SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database on Zeit.co?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sqlite, next.js, vercel

I want to connect to my database which is sqlite3. This is work fine on localhost and fail when I deployed to zeit.co with ERROR:

```
Error: SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database
```

As I understand, this issue is because we cannot get right path to database file. I have tried some solutions but still failed. Plz help!!!

Here is error on zeit.co log:

> 2020-02-13T07:50:40.031Z  4d5a9aed-ae26-4a09-903a-72aa08ca5140    ERROR   Unhandled Promise Rejection
>     {"errorType":"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection","errorMessage":"Error:
>   SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database
>   file","reason":{"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"SQLITE_CANTOPEN:
>   unable to open database
>   file","code":"SQLITE_CANTOPEN","errno":14,"stack":["Error:
>   SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database
>   file"]},"promise":{"isFulfilled":false,"isRejected":true,"rejectionReason":{"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"SQLITE_CANTOPEN:
>   unable to open database
>   file","code":"SQLITE_CANTOPEN","errno":14,"stack":["Error:
>   SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database
>   file"]}},"stack":["Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: Error:
>   SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file","    at
>   process. (/var/runtime/index.js:35:15)","    at
>   process.emit (events.js:228:7)","    at
>   eventToObjectGenerator.promiseCreated
>   (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:258:33)","
>   at activeFireEvent
>   (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:301:44)","
>   at fireRejectionEvent
>   (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:703:14)","
>   at Promise._notifyUnhandledRejection
>   (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:90:9)"," 
>   at Timeout.unhandledRejectionCheck [as _onTimeout]
>   (/var/task/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:39:25)","
>   at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)","    at processTimers
>   (internal/timers.js:475:7)"]} Unknown application error occurred

Here is the code that I connect to sqlite

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const DBSOURCE = path.join(__dirname, 'mydb.sqlite');

const knex = require('knex')({
    client: 'sqlite3',
    connection: {
        filename: DBSOURCE
    }
});
```

Note:

1. I have tried `const DBSOURCE = 'mydb.sqlite'`;
2. I have tried `const DBSOURCE = path.resolve(__dirname, 'mydb.sqlite');`

Comment: Here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69669634/nextjs-post-api-not-working-in-live-environment-but-working-perfect-on-local/69671071#69671071

Answer (score 0):

For those stumbling here from Google, Zeit is now Vercel and there's an updated example for using MySQL in serverless environments.

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-mysql